# $.get error with AJAX in Internet Explorer 8 and lower

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

The code rest of the AJAX request works fine but this `$.get` request is causing an error.

```
$.get(
    'login.php?pass=' + password , 
    function(data) {
        var check = data;
        $('#main').load(check);
    }
);
```

The error is `80020101`.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: And the error is....? I assume the missing closing braces is just a copy/paste issue?

Comment: Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: A bit more info would help. And the code you pasted does not seem complete. What is your error exactly?

Comment: The error is 80020101. I've tried a few of the possible solutions that are online but they don't seem to work.

Comment: That sounds like a server-side error with the PHP code, not the jQuery.

Comment: Are you sure that's the *whole* code? Because `80020101` gets thrown when IE cannot parse your JavaScript properly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think his php returns malformed JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hunch, so if it's wrong let me know and I'll remove my answer.

Your `login.php` script probably returns JavaScript and inside that JavaScript there's an error. Specifically look for constructs like this:

```
{
   a: 'x',
   b: 'y',
}
```

See that dangling comma before the curly closing brace? That trips up IE!

**PS** if you're sending passwords like that in the clear I sure hope you're using HTTPS

**PPS** You should use `'...?pass=' + encodeURIComponent(password)`

Comment: That worked. It's amazing how one comma can causes such a big problem. Thank you!